# SBT reports unresolved dependency for com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-start-script;0.10.0?

Tags: sbt

I use SBT **0.13.0**.

**UPDATE** it turned out that I've been using SBT **0.12.2** in the project (that I checked with `sbt sbt-version` and used `sbt --version` before).

With the following `build.sbt` SBT can't seem to be able to fetch the `sbt-start-script` plugin/dependency:

```
version := "0.1"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "play" % "play_2.10" % "2.1.0",
  "org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "2.6.3",
  "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "0.8.0",
  "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-stream" % "3.0.5"    
)

resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeResolver

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-start-script" % "0.10.0")
```

When I run `sbt clean compile stage` I get the following error:

```
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-start-script:0.10.0 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10)
[warn]
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-start-script;0.10.0: not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the line

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-start-script" % "0.10.0")
```

into its own `project/plugins.sbt` file (as is also described in [Details](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-start-script#details) of the plugin's documentation). This way the plugin gets added to the project's installed plugins (via `addSbtPlugin` method call).

In the same documentation, there's the section [Consider sbt-native-packager instead](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-start-script#consider-sbt-native-packager-instead) that says:

> The more general native-packager plugin may replace this one in the future: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager

**build.sbt** should be as follows (it's only valid to get the plugin run successfully - I have **not** checked the other settings like `libraryDependencies`):

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtStartScript

version := "0.1"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "play" % "play_2.10" % "2.1.0",
  "org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "2.6.3",
  "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "0.8.0",
  "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-stream" % "3.0.5"
)

seq(SbtStartScript.startScriptForClassesSettings: _*)
```

With the `build.sbt` and `project/plugins.sbt` in place, when you run sbt shell you should be able to generate start script for the project.

```
jacek:~/sandbox/so/sbt-start-script
$ sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-start-script/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-start-script/project/}sbt-start-script-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] downloading http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-start-script/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.10.0/jars/sbt-start-script.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-start-script;0.10.0!sbt-start-script.jar (2725ms)
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to sbt-start-script (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-start-script/)
[sbt-start-script]> start-script
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-start-script/}sbt-start-script...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/nscala-time/nscala-time_2.10/0.8.0/nscala-time_2.10-0.8.0.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.github.nscala-time#nscala-time_2.10;0.8.0!nscala-time_2.10.jar (712ms)
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/twitter4j/twitter4j-stream/3.0.5/twitter4j-stream-3.0.5.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.twitter4j#twitter4j-stream;3.0.5!twitter4j-stream.jar (441ms)
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/casbah-commons_2.10/2.6.3/casbah-commons_2.10-2.6.3.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.mongodb#casbah-commons_2.10;2.6.3!casbah-commons_2.10.jar (539ms)
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/casbah-core_2.10/2.6.3/casbah-core_2.10-2.6.3.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.mongodb#casbah-core_2.10;2.6.3!casbah-core_2.10.jar (618ms)
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/casbah-query_2.10/2.6.3/casbah-query_2.10-2.6.3.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.mongodb#casbah-query_2.10;2.6.3!casbah-query_2.10.jar (553ms)
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/casbah-gridfs_2.10/2.6.3/casbah-gridfs_2.10-2.6.3.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.mongodb#casbah-gridfs_2.10;2.6.3!casbah-gridfs_2.10.jar (462ms)
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.11.3/mongo-java-driver-2.11.3.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.mongodb#mongo-java-driver;2.11.3!mongo-java-driver.jar (605ms)
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/twitter4j/twitter4j-core/3.0.5/twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.twitter4j#twitter4j-core;3.0.5!twitter4j-core.jar (523ms)
[info] Done updating.
[info] Wrote start script for mainClass := None to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-start-script/target/start
[success] Total time: 21 s, completed Feb 15, 2014 9:43:42 PM
```

Comment: Thank you! It turned out that I had SBT version 0.12.2. I used your suggestion but changed the library to match my sbt version. What was throwing me me of is: $ sbt --version
sbt launcher version 0.13.1

$ sbt sbt-version
[info] 0.12.2

Comment: `sbtVersion` is set in `project/build.properties`. It can be as high as the version of the launcher (which in your case could be `0.13.2-M1`).

Comment: Good point! I did do that when testing the solution by Sari HH

Answer (score 0):

For Play 2.1.0.

In `project/build.properties` use:

```
sbt.version=0.12.2
```

In `project/plugins.sbt` use:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1.0")
```

In `project/Build.scala` use:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
    val appName         = "your_app_name"
    val appVersion      = "1.0"

    val appDependencies = Seq(
        // project dependencies
    )

    val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
        // project settings
    )
}
```

It remains a good idea to clear the content of your `.ivy2` cache which you can find on your system drive. Then do:

```
play clean-all
play compile
play ~run
```

Comment: No dice. Got the following:

[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: play#sbt-plugin;2.1.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-start-script;0.10.0: not found

Comment: Thanks, I actually don't have a play project. I just have play as a dependency for working with JSON